# Magento 2 Add / Edit Category in theme custom module with multiselect

Tags: module, magento2

```php
$fieldset->addField(
        'category_ids',
        'Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Category',
        [
            'name' => 'category_ids',
            'title' => 'Category',
            'label' => 'Category'
        ]
    );
```

I have included the above code in `tab/main.php`, and it shows the default Magento categories, I need the category to be **multi-select** and where to save and edit the values, in which files I have code to save.

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: i have add the magento 2 category fieldset in my custom module, i want it to be multiselect dropdown and it should store the  category id values in my custom table , hope u understand

Comment: anybody there to guide me ??